# A question of the completeness and linearly independent of sequence {x^k}

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

The question is:

> Given a finite closed interval $[a,b]$, prove the following statements:
>   (1)$\{x^k\}_{k\geq 0}$ is a complete and linearly independent sequence in $L^2[a,b]$.
>   (2)$\{x^k\}_{k\geq N}$ is a complete and linearly independent sequence in $L^2[a,b]$ for each integer $N \in \mathbb{N}$.

I met this question on a book(the name of the book is "An Introduction to Real Analysis" by Dr. Christopher Heil) and I have no clue. Could anyone help me solve this?

[image]

Comment: What's the name of the book you where you found the question? You might want to add that to the question ;)

Comment: Added, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Outline of proof.**

For linear independence, consider a linear combinations $\sum a_k x_k = 0$ in $\mathscr{L}^2,$ that is to say, $\int (\sum a_k x_k)^2 = 0.$ Since a polynomial function is continuous, we actually get $\sum a_k x^k = 0$ pointwise. So, we have a polynomial that is identically zero, then each coefficient is zero (by say, taking successive derivatives and then evaluating at zero).

To see it is complete, apply the Stone-Weierstrass theorem, so that each continuous function can be uniformly approximated by polynomials and therefore, since $\|f\|_2 \leq (b-a)\|f\|_\infty,$ every function in $\mathscr{L}^2_\mathbf{R}([a, b])$ can be approximated by polynomials.

For part b), observe that $(x^k)_{k \geq N}$ generates an algebra that separates points put that is null at zero. The Stone-Weierstrass theorem then says that its closure in $\mathscr{C}_\mathbf{R}([a, b])$ (with respect to the supremum norm) is the set of continuous functions defines on $[a, b]$ such $f(0) = 0$ if $0 \in [a, b]$ and it is *all continuous functions* if $0 \notin [a, b].$ In the latter case, the proof follows from a), so assume $0 \in [a, b].$ Hence, for a function $f \in \mathscr{L}^2$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ given, consider $f_\varepsilon$ which is equal to $f$ on all of $[a, b]$ except on an interval around zero of radius $\varepsilon.$ Then, $f_\varepsilon \to f$ in $\mathscr{L}^2$ (by Lebesgue dominated converge theorem) so it suffices to approximate $f_\varepsilon.$ Approximate it by a continuous function that is zero on an interval around zero of radius $\varepsilon/2$ and then approximate this continuous function by polynomials in the algebra generated by $(x^k)_{k \geq N}.$

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, there is a nice characterization when working in a Hilbert space like $L^2[a,b]$. That is $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is complete if whenever $\langle x,x_n\rangle = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $x = 0$. Suppose $f \in L^2[a,b]$ such that $\langle f,x^k\rangle = 0$ for $k \geq N$. Then for every $k \geq N$ we can write $k = j+N$ where $j \geq 0$. So,
$$0 = \int_a^bf(x) x^k \, dx = \int_a^b f(x)x^{j
+N} \, dx = \int_a^b (f(x)x^N)x^j \, dx.$$ This is true for all $j \geq 0$ and by the previous part we must have $f(x)x^N = 0$ on $[a,b]$. Hence $f=0$.